# Select for login and update at the same time

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, c#-4.0, sql-update

Is it possible to use `SQL command` for login and `update` at the same time? I mean when the Login is done, I want to change `logat in 1`. Do I have to create a new `if` with `OpenConnection()`?

```
public bool IsLogin(string user, string pass) {
            string query = $"SELECT * from utiliz WHERE username='{user}' AND password='{GetSha1(pass)}'";
            string query_update = $"UPDATE utiliz SET logat='{1}' WHERE username='{user}'";
            try
            {
                if (OpenConnection())
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        conn.Close();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    conn.Close();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                conn.Close();
                return false;
            }
            }
```

**EDITED**

Guys, I have edited my code, following parameters procedure. Is it good what I did?

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_pass_login.Text) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_usr_login.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_usr_login.Text) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox_pass_login.Text))
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Both fields (username,password) are required");
            }
            else
            {
                string user = textBox_usr_login.Text;
                string password = textBox_pass_login.Text;
                string encryptedpass = GetSha1(password);
                try
                {
                    using (var connection = conn)
                    {
                        string query = "SELECT * from utiliz WHERE username=@user AND password=@password";
                        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                        {
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encryptedpass);
                            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            conn.Open();
                            int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                this.Hide();
                                var form2 = new Form1();
                                form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
                                form2.Show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Wrong credentials");
                                textBox_usr_login.Clear();
                                textBox_pass_login.Clear();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Wrong credentials");
                    textBox_usr_login.Clear();
                    textBox_pass_login.Clear();
                }    
            }
```

Comment: **Yes** it's possible to verify (select) and then do an update all in one statement. On another note, use parameters to *prevent* injection, use `using` statements to release resources when done with them. More than likely you don't need `OpenConnection()`, you should be opening your connection, do what you need and then get out (if this is the case then `IsLogin` can be static. Finally, are you using `MySQL` *or* `SQL`, it's not clear.

Comment: You should do this with a stored procedure and pass parameters instead of strings. My friend [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like this.

Comment: @SeanLange always love seeing that :)

Comment: Almost forgot, don't store plain text passwords either; very bad idea, store a hashed version of the password and then do your hash on the provided password and then compare them to verify a user...

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. I will try to solve it:)

Comment: A) Use a password-specific hash like [Bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), **never** plain-text passwords. SHA1 is trash, it can't be trusted for anything, especially not passwords. B) Use **placeholder values** and **never** inject data of any kind into your query.

Answer (score 1):

There are some important points here. You must use Parameterized queries to improve the performence of your query on the database layer and avoid some problems such as `sql injection`. You also could use transactions to keep data integrity.

Check the sample bellow with comments (I didn't test this code, may not work properly on your environment):

```
public bool IsLogin(string user, string pass) 
{
    // prepare the queries with parameters with '@' and parameter name
    const string query = "SELECT count(username) from utiliz WHERE username = @username AND password = @password";
    const string query_update = "UPDATE utiliz SET logat = @logat WHERE username = @username";

    // prepare the encrypted password
    string encryptedPass = GetSha1(pass);

    // use a result variable to use as the function result

    bool result = false;
    try
    {
        if (OpenConnection())
        {
            // start a transaction from the connection object
            using (MySqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try    
                {
                    int userFound = 0;
                    // prepare the MySqlCommand to use the query, connection and transaction.
                    using (MySqlCommand userCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, conn, tran))
                    {
                        userCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);
                        userCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encryptedPass);

                        userFound = (int) userCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    }  

                    if (userFound > 0)
                    {
                        // prepare the MySqlCommand to use the query, connection and transaction to update data
                        using (MySqlCommand logatCommand = new MySqlCommand(query_update, conn, tran))
                        {
                            logatCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logat", DateTime.Now);
                            logatCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", user);                        

                            logatCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }  

                    // commit the transaction
                    tran.Commit();

                    result = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // perform some log with ex object. 


                    tran.Rollback();
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // perform some log...

        return false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to prevent SQL injection for windows form apps? SQL injection is not only for web development?

Comment: `userFound = (int) userCommand.ExecuteScalar();` is returing 0, do you know why?

Comment: SQL injection is a bug. If someone signs up with a username of "O'Malley" your app crashes. That's the mildest form of problem. The correct way to add data is with placeholder values, that ensures anything you supply, even if it's raw binary data, is inserted properly.

Comment: @Paul -- no sql injection is not just web applications.

Comment: @Paul If your application concats strings, then it can have a sql injection issue! It is returning `0` because there no result on the  query. The `ExecuteScalar()` method will return the first column and row on the result set. Take a look on the query, I change it to a `count` and I am not sure if you could do this.

Answer (score 1):

As recommended (and demonstrated) by Felipe Oriani, you should use parameterized queries.

Let me pinpoint, however, that you *can* do this with a single `update` query. The trick is to filter the update query on both user name and password:

```
UPDATE utiliz SET logat = @logat WHERE username = @username AND password = @password
```

You want to run the query with method [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8), which returns the number of rows affected.

If credentials are valid, the `where` cause selects the relevant record and the update happens, returning `1` as the count of records affected. Else, no record is updated, and the method returns `0`.

Comment: I have changed the entire logic of login, can you please take a look and tell me if it is good, to avoid `sql injection`? @GMB